# What does the healattribute do?

Tags: loadout

I could buy the heal attribute for my weapon.

I tested it in testmode and it seemed like i would heal the testdummies.

Do weapons with that attribute only heal , even enemies?

Can you do damage too?

Is there any reason i would take a rocket launcher with heal then instead of a beam?

Does a rocket launcher heal more per hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Healing weapons heal your teammates only, not your enemies.  There is no way to deal damage with a healing weapon.

If you try different parts in the weaponcrafting menu, the gun will show you the 'healing' stat instead of damage; you can use this to find the values you like (I'm not sure which one is the most efficient but I suspect it's beam).

In terms of choosing different types of weapons, rockets will allow you have splash healing (particularly if you use flak warheads) which can be very useful in the *Blitz* gamemode.  Rockets can also be used to heal *yourself*, but the efficiency of self-healing is significantly lower than when healing another player.  Beams will give you long range healing, and usually be more efficient as well, but require greater accuracy.  Rifle healing seems pretty popular as well, but I've never tried it.  And pulse has the bounce shot effect, which can be an asset in enclosed spaces.  Rifle and Pulse weapons can also be made into shotguns.  Choose the weapon type that suits your playstyle.  Experiment!

Note that healing another player will also heal you, faster than self-healing with a rocket would.  It's possible to overheal yourself just by healing other players

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

http://loadout.wikia.com/wiki/Payloads

Also:

http://loadout.wikia.com/wiki/Health

Specifically for your question:

- Do weapons with that attribute only heal , even enemies?

Can be used to heal players on the same team as the user (including the user himself combined with launchers or pulse weapons with bouncy or rebounding)

- Can you do damage too?

Disadvantages: Deals no damage to enemies.

I dont know about the rocket launcher questions though. You should test this yourself with a friend.

Comment: I use a rocket healer, does no damage to enemies.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Ok but why is this exactly a comment on my answer?

Comment: because you said you were unsure about rocket launchers doing no damage to enemies.  I answered that for you. =]

Comment: @GnomeSlice Ow no i meant I dont know about the rocket launcher though answering the rocket launcher questions he had :). Wasn't meant for the damage thing.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.

Comment: @GnomeSlice No my mistake. Sorry. Should have been more clear.